# is there a open source way to georeference a non geospatial vector (like eps, svg etc)?

Tags: georeferencing, open-source-gis

Is it possible to reference a non geospatial vector file such as eps, pdf, svg, dxf etc.? 
The vectors I'm talking about are points and lines without any georeferences, but the size, the position and the CRS of their bounding box is known.

Since there are some thousands of vectors, the rasterize -> georeference -> vectorize way is no solution.

Comment: QGIS has the tools `assign projection` and `translategeometry`. In combination they should do what you need, but I don't know how easy to use they are in a batch.

Comment: In GRASS GIS, take a look at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.transform.html for affine transform, optionally in batch mode.

Comment: Maybe the qgsAffine plugin can be of help.